# Google Play Protect doesn't recognized this app developer error after resetting my laptop

Tags: android-studio

Before, I had coded an app on my laptop, and when I built the APK file for the app, there were no issues with installing it on my phone. However, after resetting my laptop and reinstalling Android Studio, I have been facing a problem. Every time I build the APK file and try to install it on my phone, Google Play Protect doesn't recognize the app error is displayed.

Comment: I speculate here, but it sounds like an environment variable exported in the terminal without being permanently added to the PATH. When you end your terminal session (which restarting the laptop does) these vars go away. Try to remember if you've exported such vars while initially setting up your studio/project

Also you should include your environment (operating system) in your question